# How do I reorder rows manually by using column values in SQL

Tags: if-statement, sql-order-by

I have a table like this

```
EmployeeID    Gender     JobTitle
1             F          A
2             M          A
3             M          B
4             M          C
5             F          C
```

My desired table is like this:

```
           Male    Female
Manager    1       1
```

The query I wrote is :

```
SELECT 'A' as Category, 
  sum( IIF(Gender = 'M' and JobTitle= 'A', 1,0)) as Male, 
  sum( IIF(Gender = 'F' and Manager= 'A', 1,0)) as Female, 
 FROM Table 
UNION 
(SELECT 'B' as Category, 
  sum( IIF(Gender = 'M' and JobTitle= 'B', 1,0)) as Male, 
  sum( IIF(Gender = 'F' and Manager= 'B', 1,0)) as Female, 
 FROM Table
)
 UNION 
(SELECT 'C' as Category, 
  sum( IIF(Gender = 'M' and JobTitle= 'C', 1,0)) as Male, 
  sum( IIF(Gender = 'F' and Manager= 'C', 1,0)) as Female, 
 FROM Table
)
```

And I got:

```
Category       Male    Female
A              1       1
B              1       0
C              1       1
```

What if I want to reorder the rows, say

```
 Category       Male    Female
  B              1       0
  A              1       1
  C              1       1
```

Since I am using ODBC, case when statement is not supported.
How should I wrote using iif statement? Or any other better approach?